# How to display a custom keyboard

Tags: html, ibm-mobilefirst

I am creating a Worklight 6.1-based app with Dojo.

I want to present a 10-key keyboard to the user instead of the standard OS keyboard. How would I go about doing this?

I've tried the following, but it does not bring up a numbers-only keyboard. In iOS it brings up the full keyboard, only with the view that has numbers and $%^&* keys.

```
<input type='number' data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.TextBox'>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To successfully display a numeric keyboard you need to add the `pattern` attribute to the `input` element, like so:

```
<input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" type="number" pattern="\d*">
```

I do not have an Android device, but it should work there as well.
Note that unlike in iOS where there is only 1 keyboard, in Android a user can install custom keyboard and it could be that not all keyboards will support the full set of customizability available...

There is nothing Worklight can do about that. (Worse case scenario you can [write a Cordova plug-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova) to create a custom keyboard of your own, but it's unlikely you'll need to do that).

Here is how it looks like:
[image]

Here is some more reading materials on customizing a keyboard:

- http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/better-numerical-inputs-for-mobile-forms/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/
- https://about.zoosk.com/en/engineering-blog/mobile-web-design-use-html5-to-trigger-the-appropriate-keyboard-for-form-inputs/
- http://danielfriesen.name/blog/2013/09/19/input-type-number-and-ios-numeric-keypad/
- http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/10-pattern.html
- Google

Comment: is there any way to get the decimal to show on the keyboard?  I've tried different patterns and none seem to work.

Comment: Now there is a inputmode attribute for that
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode