# Disable automatic keyboard correction on HTML input

Tags: android, html, keyboard

For a web application open on Android Chrome. Is it possible to disable automatic keyboard correction on a specific HTML input.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Including following attributes in an input or textarea will disable this:

```
autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"
```

e.g.

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" />
```

Comment: I misread your question a bit, sorry. As Pankaj Sati mentioned, it is not possible to hide suggestions by the keyboard-app itself. You can only disable autocorrected input, the capitalization and spellchecking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to disable Android's automatic keyboard correction for an input type in HTML.

But you can show a custom keyboard instead of standard Android OS keyboard. With your own keyboard you will have more flexibility over the user input. You can also reduce some keys or add keys for special symbols if you want.

Checkout this form for more details. It has links to some articles which will help you to implement it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22876767/10602679

Comment: my problem that I have an event to fire onKeyup, but on android this event is blocked, it is fired once we click on a suggested suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=901839).

In fact, the behavior of that row changes based on the HTML element (try `<input type="password" autocorrect="newpassword" />` and see the suggestions turn into 0-9 numbers).  Chrome needs to respect what developers intend to.

Please upvote/star that bug.