# How to remove word hints on android?

Tags: javascript

I have those hints [image]

Have can I remove it from browser by android?

Is this possible with `JavaScript`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable automatic keyboard correction on HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405637/disable-automatic-keyboard-correction-on-html-input)

Comment: Tl;Dr you can't control the keyboard app in Android its up to the user if they want to disable that.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, disable the [`autocomplete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete), [`spellcheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck), [`autocorrect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#autocorrect), and [`autocapitalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autocapitalize)  attributes on the [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element.

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" />
```

Do you want to do it through JavaScript? Use the [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method.

```js
const text = document.getElementById("text");

text.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
text.setAttribute("autocorrect", "off");
text.setAttribute("autocapitalize", "off");
text.setAttribute("spellcheck", "false");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" />
```

Comment: It's not work. Android browser still continue to show me hints

Comment: Well then, @EduardRST, you should show your current code so we can really understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Even your code doesn't work. The android keyboard ignores all hints in input. As in my photo from android browser.

Comment: Then again, @EduardRST, you should show your code, I'm not going to guess what's your current code, but my code should really work. You can read about each attribute though.

Answer (score -1):

something like:

```
const MyTextInput = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        autoCorrect={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

With the autoCorrect={false} property set, the word suggestions and corrections should be disabled for the TextInput in your app.

Comment: It's Js? Have can it help me this code?

Comment: IIRC, this is [React](https://react.dev/). @EduardRST